# Дебаг Jenkins проектов из IDEA

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Есть какая-нибудь возможность продебажить дженкинс проект внутри idea?Находил плагины которые позволяют только их запускать.

Comment: Поясни, что ты подразумеваешь под понятием `дженкинс проект`. Вообще ты можешь дебажить любую удалённую JVM, подключившись с специальному порту.

Comment: В моём случае это pipeline проект и необходимо продебажить jenkinsfile.